# How to create RTL text for arabic and other right to left languages

Tags: html, right-to-left

How are you meant to set text for Arabic.
As I understand it, if the following sentence was arabic:
"The cat sat on the mat"
it would be aligned right and mirrored to read from right to left:
"tam eht no tas tac ehT"

However if you use the dir="rtl" property it doesn't do this. 
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_global_dir

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

You misunderstand the `dir` attribute.

The ordering of characters within each word shown is determined by the Unicode bidirectional algorithm, not by the dir attribute.

In other words, languages like English read left to right. However, with other languages such as Arabic, the Unicode algorithm will render it right to left.

From W3 themselves.

> In order for text to look right when an HTML page is displayed, we need to establish the directional context of that text. We will refer to that context as the base direction for the text.
>
> It is fundamentally important to establish the appropriate base direction for the Unicode bidirectional algorithm to produce the expected ordering of the displayed text. Correct specification of the base direction also establishes a proper default alignment for the text.
>
> In HTML the base direction is either set explicitly by the nearest parent element that uses the dir attribute, or, in the absence of such an attribute, the base direction is inherited from the default direction of the document, which is left-to-right (LTR).
>
> **Adding dir="rtl" to the html element will cause block elements and table columns to start on the right and flow from right to left**. All block elements in the document will inherit this setting unless the direction is explicitly overridden.

Reference

http://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-html-dir